# Moving nth elements around to a specific nth element in a string in python?

Tags: python, string, for-loop

Okay so I'm new to Python, trying to move away from Java.

Basically I want to switch the index of a string from 0 to 1, the now switched 1 to 4, the old 4th to 5th and so on.

For an example

`string_msg = ['HBTUET']` 
needs to print out `['BUTTHE']`

How do I do this?

What I've tried so far

```
string_msg = 'HBTUET'
lst = list(string_msg)
lst[::2], lst[1::2] = lst[1::2], lst[::2]
''.join(lst)
print(lst)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you share some of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I've edited it and posted what i've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Strings are an immutable data type, so you can't rearrange the characters in a string. However, you can use the `list()` function to convert the string to a list, rearrange the items, then use the `str.join()` method to convert the list back to a string.

I'm not exactly sure what the pattern is supposed to be in switching the characters, so I just switched the specific cases which you mentioned.

```py
string = "HBTUET"
list_string = list(string)

list_string[0], list_string[1] = list_string[1], list_string[0]
list_string[1], list_string[4] = list_string[4], list_string[1]
list_string[4], list_string[5] = list_string[5], list_string[4]

new_string = "".join(list_string)
```

Obviously you would have to rearrange the index assignment statements to match the exact procedure desired, but this is a basic layout.

If you have pre-set positions to switch, then it would be easy to use a `for` loop to switch all the specified items.

```py
string = "HBTUET"
list_string = list(string)
positions = [(0, 1), (1, 4), (4, 5)]

for tup in positions:
    list_string[tup[0]], list_string[tup[1]] = list_string[tup[1]], list_string[tup[0]]

mew_string = "".join(list_string)
```

Alternatively, if there is a specific pattern for switching the characters, e.g. transpose one position right:

```py
string = "HBTUET"
list_string = list(string)

for i in range(len(list_string)-1):
    list_string[i], list_string[i+1] = list_string[i+1], list_string[i]

new_string = ''.join(list_string)
```

Comment: Hi thats perfect, however, how would I make that into a loop? Say I have way too many characters, and the process of writing out list_string is too long. Is there a loop I can do which just reformats each nth by a specific position? For instance,  say we use your method, and say I increase the amount in a string, how would I make it so it repeats a change for every nth character?

Comment: @hyeholestgo If you have multiple values, there are two options I can think of off of the top of my head. (1) Make a list of tuples of pairs of indexes to switch. Make sure that the items are ordered properly, otherwise you may end up with a different string. You can then iterate through each tuple in the list and do something like `list_string[tup[0]], list_string[tup[1]] = list_string[tup[1]], list_string[tup[0]]`. (2) If each character were to be transposed, you could just do `list_string[i], list_string[i+1] = list_string[i+1], list_string[i]`. *(1) would be my suggested approach.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of tuples to express the index swapping but you have to be careful with the order of these swap operations:

```
def strSwap(msg,swaps):
    chars = list(msg)
    for i,j in swaps: chars[i],chars[j] = chars[j],chars[i]
    return "".join(chars)
```

output:

```
msg   = 'HBTUET'
swaps = [(0,1),(1,3),(3,5),(4,5)]    

strSwap(msg,swaps) # 'BUTTHE'


msg   = 'WRFLVEOO'
swaps = [(0,7),(1,2),(1,4),(2,3),(2,5)]

strSwap(msg,swaps) # 'OVERFLOW'


msg   = 'ESLHTYGOHOE'
swaps = [(0, 1), (0, 8), (2, 5), (4, 7), (6, 9), (6, 10)]

print(strSwap(msg,swaps)) # 'HEYHOLETSGO'
```